# Is there anyone can explain this python code for me

Tags: python

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()
```

I want to know how is this peace of code work in python. If you can explain this with some examples it's better for me.

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: scores = list(map(float, line))

Comment: The [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function calls the [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) function on each element in `line`. Then the `list` call converts the iterator returned my `map` to a `list`. So you end up with a `list` of `float` values.

Answer (score 1):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
# This is a convention. 
# Run code below if the file is running directly, not imported as a module.

    n = int(input())
    # Ask user to type something in terminal 
    # and convert it from string to integer (a number) type

    student_marks = {}
    # Create a new object (dictionary) for storing some data

    for _ in range(n):
        # Just iterate N times

        name, *line = input().split()
        # During every iteration:
        # Ask a user to type multiple words, split it by whitespace
        # First word we have as name, the rest put in a new list named line

        scores = list(map(float, line))
        # Create list names scored containing values from line, 
        # each converted to a floating point (float) type

        student_marks[name] = scores
        # Create a new key in student_marks disctionary 
        # named as a student name, put his scores there

    query_name = input()
    # Ask user to input some text in terminal, 
    # place it to a query_name variable
```